# TypeError: int object is not subscriptable while passing a dataframe to a pipeline

Tags: python, typeerror, pipeline

I created a pipeline for data preprocessing (encoding textual data and normalization ). I am getting a typeerror which I am not able to understand. Posting the part of the code. The error is in the last and second last lines of the code where I am trying to pass the dataframe to a pipeline. Any help or direction is highly appreciated. Thank you :)

#### Separating textual features

```
HDFC_Working_Train_CN = HDFC_Working_Train.loc[ : ,['Candle Nature']]

HDFC_Working_Train_CT = HDFC_Working_Train.loc[ : ,['Candle Type']]

HDFC_Working_Train_DR = HDFC_Working_Train.loc[ : ,['Direction']]

HDFC_Working_Train_TR = HDFC_Working_Train.loc[ : ,['Target']]
```

#### Separating numerical features

```
HDFC_Working_Train_num = HDFC_Working_Train.drop(['Candle Nature', 'Candle Type', 'Direction', 'Target'], axis = 1)
```

#### DATA PREPROCESSING

```
class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values
```

#### Min Max scaling with range (0, 1)

```
num_pipeline_1 = Pipeline([

 ('selector_1', DataFrameSelector(list(HDFC_Working_Train_num))),

 ('scaler_1', MinMaxScaler(0, 1)),

 ])
```

#### Min Max Scaling with range (-1, 1)

```
num_pipeline_2 = Pipeline([

 ('selector_2', DataFrameSelector(list(HDFC_Working_Train_num))),

 ('scaler_2', MinMaxScaler(-1, 1)),

 ])
```

#### Encoding Candle Nature

```
cat_pipeline_1 = Pipeline([

 ('selector_1', DataFrameSelector(HDFC_Working_Train_CN)),

 ('label_binarizer_1', LabelBinarizer()),

 ])
```

#### Encoding Candle Type

```
cat_pipeline_2 = Pipeline([

 ('selector_2', DataFrameSelector(HDFC_Working_Train_CT)),

 ('label_binarizer_2', LabelBinarizer()),

 ])
```

#### Encoding Direction

```
cat_pipeline_3 = Pipeline([

('selector_3', DataFrameSelector(HDFC_Working_Train_DR)),

('label_binarizer_3', LabelBinarizer()),

 ])
```

#### Encoding Target

```
cat_pipeline_4 = Pipeline([

 ('selector_4', DataFrameSelector(HDFC_Working_Train_TR)),

 ('label_binarizer_4', LabelBinarizer()),

])
```

#### Creating a dataset with (0, 1) normalization

```
full_pipeline_1 = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[

 ("num_pipeline_1", num_pipeline_1),

 ("cat_pipeline_1", cat_pipeline_1),

 ("cat_pipeline_2", cat_pipeline_2),

 ("cat_pipeline_3", cat_pipeline_3),

 ("cat_pipeline_4", cat_pipeline_4),

 ])
```

#### Creating a dataset with (-1, 1) normalization

```
full_pipeline_2 = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[

 ("num_pipeline_2", num_pipeline_2),

 ("cat_pipeline_1", cat_pipeline_1),

 ("cat_pipeline_2", cat_pipeline_2),

 ("cat_pipeline_3", cat_pipeline_3),

 ("cat_pipeline_4", cat_pipeline_4),

 ])

HDFC_MM1 = full_pipeline_1.fit_transform(HDFC_Working_Train)

HDFC_MM2 = full_pipeline_2.fit_transform(HDFC_Working_Train)
```

*The error is as follows:*

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-8-ff2f118d9924> in <module>


396  ])

397
```

--> 398 HDFC_MM1 = full_pipeline_1.fit_transform(HDFC_Working_Train)

```
399 

400 HDFC_MM2 = full_pipeline_2.fit_transform(HDFC_Working_Train)



TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Typically this error comes when you are trying to index a variable assuming its a list but actually it is an `int`  Just double check the variables by priniting their values

Comment: By variables do you mean the column values in the dataframe?

Comment: You say you can't locate it exactly. But the stack trace tells you exactly where. Edit your question to include it. Even if you can't read it, we can. And you can't debug any but the simplest code until you have learnt how. The stack trace is the bit that begins *most recent call last* and ends with the message you posted.

Comment: I have made the changes. Thank you. Any thoughts on how I can resolve this?